# Count items in one cell array in another cell array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have 2 cell arrays which are "celldata" and "data" . Both of them store strings inside. Now I would like to check each element in "celldata" whether in "data" or not? For example, celldata = {'AB'; 'BE'; 'BC'} and data={'ABCD' 'BCDE' 'ACBE' 'ADEBC '}. I would like the expected output will be   s=3 and v= 1 for AB, s=2 and v=2 for  BE, s=2 and v=2 for BC, because I just need to count the sequence of the string in 'celldata'

The code I wrote is shown below. Any help would be certainly appreciated.
**My code:**

```
s=0; support counter
v=0; violate counter
SV=[]; % array to store the support
VV=[]; % array to store the violate

pairs = ['AB'; 'BE'; 'BC']
%celldata = cellstr(pairs)
celldata = {'AB'; 'BE'; 'BC'}
data={'ABCD' 'BCDE' 'ACBE' 'ADEBC '} % 3 AB, 2 BE, 2 BC

for jj=1:length(data)
    for kk=1:length(celldata)

res = regexp( data(jj),celldata(kk) )

m = cell2mat(res);
e=isempty(m)  % check res array is empty or not
if e == 0
    s = s + 1;
    SV(jj)=s;
    v=v;
else
    s=s;
    v= v+1;
    VV(jj)=v;
end
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, what are `s` and `v`? I'm not seeing rhyme or reason in how they relate?

Comment: s means how many support where the sequence "AB" appears in the cell array "data={'ABCD' 'BCDE' 'ACBE' 'ADEBC '}". In this case, we have 3 "AB" sequence( "ACBE' can be counted as including 1 "AB"  here). Therefore, s is 3

Comment: Okay but you haven't explained what a support is. Not everyone answering questions works in your field. Is it the number of strings that both 'A' and 'B' appear? And you haven't explained what `v` is either. Is `v = 4 - s`?

Comment: So which of these count towards `s` using "AB"? "ABCD", "ACBE, "ADEBC", "BACD", "EBDA"?

Comment: The support is that both "A" and 'B" appear, and 'A' is before 'B', if both of these conditions are satified, s=s+1 . Thanks

Comment: "using "AB"? "ABCD", "ACBE, "ADEBC", "BACD", "EBDA"?" =>  s=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your variables correctly, `s` is the number of cells which the substring `AB`, `AE` and, `BC` does not appear and `v` is the number of times it does. If this is accurate then

```
v = cellfun(@(x) length(cell2mat(strfind(data, x))), celldata);
s = numel(data) - v;
```

gives

```
v = [1;1;3];
s = [3;3;1];
```

Comment: For these count towards s using "AB"? "ABCD", "ACBE, "ADEBC", "BACD", "EBDA" . The support is that both "A" and 'B" appear, and 'A' is before 'B', if both of these conditions are satified, s = 4 in this case . Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It seems that your code does not match with my intend , but you are very kind :)